# How can I prevent overwriting changes to a ticket that was recently updated?

Tags: trac

If I make an edit to a Trac ticket, but someone beat me to it, this message is displayed:

[image: Trac conflict message]

Ideally, I would read this message and figure out what I can overwrite and what I should not. But, depending on this message to keep users from overwriting what was submitted is [not something that we should depend on](https://blog.codinghorror.com/teaching-users-to-read/):

> This may sound a little harsh, but you'll see, when you do usability tests, that there are quite a few users who simply do not read words that you put on the screen. If you pop up an error box of any sort, they simply will not read it.

Is there a better way to prevent these overwrites in Trac - e.g., if a ticket has been modified while you were modifying it, you must refresh the page, etc?

Comment: You might be better off asking in UX (user experience) as this is really an interface question rather than a programming issue.

Comment: @dave The problem is clearly a UX issue, but my company uses Trac for typical issue tracking. I'm looking for a solution that we can directly implement in Trac, like a [TracPlugin](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracPlugins) that either already exists or I can write myself. Obviously a philosophical answer to this problem would be more suited for the UX.SE.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if the server would send the page modified outside and if the javascript running in your browser could merge that into your local changes. But noone has implemented it in the current trac.